# Using currency format without currency code

Tags: java, jsf, currency-formatting

How can i format the currency without currency symbols. When i use

```
<f:convertNumber currencyCode="TRY" type="currency"/>
```

it shows the output like

> TRY7,057.71

If I don't use

> currencyCode="TRY"

then it shows $ symbol. I just want to format numbers like 7,057.71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just format it as a number will do?

```
<f:convertNumber type="number" pattern="#,###.##" />
```